# Error “The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, ….could not be located

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created a simplest ASP.NET web forms app using Visual Studio 2019. It works OK from Visual Studio.
Then I deployed the app on the same computer into IIS 10. Running the app I get the following error:

Parser Error Message: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located

I have checked out that the file Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll does exist and that it has really been deployed into IIS. What causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have Rosyln setup and installed on that web server. however, it depends on your deployment model. If you using a asp.net "application" then at publish time, your site is already pre-compiled, and it should not matter. However, ONE big exception exists, and that is if you have/use app_code folder.

What I do now is rename that folder to MyCode, and for any code placed inside of that folder, I right click, choose properties, and set the build action to compile. Thus, at that point, you don't care if Roslyn is installed or not.
(It does not matter if you have Rosyln on the IIS server, since your site is pre-compiled, and source code is tripped out at build time.

However, if you deploying a web site (which does NOT pre-compile at deployment time), then this is "more difficult", since your code modules in pages and in app_code are NOT pre-compiled, and thus IIS now will attempt to re-compile such code.
(This by the way is a BIG reason to work with a asp.net web site "application" as opposed to using a asp.net web site).

So, you need to ensure that Rosslyn support is installed on IIS.

Or, you can do this during a publish, but you STILL have to get rid of the app_code folder (or re-name it like I did to avoid this "difficulty".

I would consider re-installing Rosyln support on your dev box, and for that project add the nugget package:

[image]

And another way? Remove and don't use Rosslyn compiler options. However, doing that could well mean some changes to your project and code - depending on how many options you used from Rosslyn.

So, after you build, and create the published folder? Check the bin folder, do you see the Roslyn support files in that folder?

As noted, you have not mentioned what kind of publishing model you are using. If this is an "application", then most easy is to just rename app_code, and set the properties of each module/class in app_code to compile at build time.